# Eclipse not detecting my Galaxy S3 GT-I9305 in list of devices

Tags: android, eclipse, driver, samsung-mobile

I know this question has been asked numerous times, but none of the threads have had an answer to solve my problem. It seems no matter what i try Eclipse just wont detect my phone, I have set it to debug mode in the settings, i've installed "Kies 3" on my laptop and it says i have the latest drivers already installed on my phone when i try to update it.

I've installed the google USB driver package from the sdk manager and have downloaded and installed the samsung driver from the samsung website. Windows recognizes the device and in the device manager under android phone it appears as "SAMSUNG android ADB Inerface".

Im running windows 7 and have even tried deleting all the mounted dive drivers from regedit as i seen suggested in another thread but still no joy! Really starting to get frustrated with this at this stage i've been trying for two days now to figure this out!

This is such a pain! I need to be able to debug on my phone too as i'm using features that the emulator can't handle (i.e. audio recording). I'm all out of ideas here so any help would really be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: 1) Are you using a custom ROM?
2) what Android version is your phone running?

Comment: Reset your adb from eclipse.

Comment: Have you tick the debug option on in your phone ?

Comment: No the phone hasn't been rooted. I'm running android 4.3

Comment: @Kedarnath He said he did

Comment: Does Windows recognize your phone? e.g. can you access it's phone/card memory from My Computer?

Comment: Yes windows recognizes the device and in the device manager under android phone it appears as SAMSUNG android ADB Inerface

Comment: In command prompt, type "adb kill-server" then "adb start-server" and then check the list of devices attached to eclipse using "adb devices"

Comment: Did you try without Kies? Uninstall Kies completely

Answer (score 1):

The method I followed to install my GT-I9300 drivers was this:

Download samsung drivers from this link:
http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows

Then just connect your phone and make sure you have a stable Internet connection: It will download required drivers *automatically*.

Also, make sure you have enabled Android developer options in your phone settings. Enable USB debugging in developer options.

Answer (score 1):

I usually get it to work, when I switch the USB mode in my smartphone (e.g. MTP to PTP). This way, windows starts downloading more drivers.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try disconnecting device from PC, revoke USB Debug authorization from settings menu, and then re-authorize the computer you are working on once you connect it again.

2) Check to see if you see the phone in DDMS perspective (left hand side) - if so, try clicking on it and it should work.

3) try removing all drivers (Google, Samsung etc.) + scan "leftover" registery entries using a reg cleaning program. Then install ONLY Kies Light version and try again.

4) It once worked for me - try changing the USB cable (preferably, to an original one)

Let us know if something worked!

Answer (score 0):

1) enable USB debugging in your phone's settings.

2) ensure that you have the proper drivers installed.

3) open adb in command prompt and run "adb connect"